# Spring WebFlow2.. action-state?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I am using Spring WebFlow2 and I would like to use a action-state to call my controller and check some server side code and then do something base on the return code..

Should I be using a action-state?

Here is my flowcode:

```
<action-state id="isMemeber">
     <evaluate expression="FlowActions.isMemeber(member)" />
     <transition on="SUCCESS" to="endStateMemeberExists" />
     <transition on="FAIL" to="isDeceased" />
</action-state>
```

Here is my Java code:

```
public void isMemeber(Member customer)
    {

    }
```

How do I return the SUCCESS or FAIL for Web Flow knows what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<action-state id="isMemeber">
   <evaluate expression="FlowActions.isMemeber(member)" />
   <transition on="yes" to="endStateMemeberExists" />
   <transition on="no" to="isDeceased" />
 </action-state>

public boolean isMemeber(Member customer)
{

}
```

[Here is the link to the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/actions.html)